# Is there a way to get georeferenced satellite tiles of any location on Earth?

Tags: tiles, satellite

I'm looking for a way to server or command line interface that a program can use to automatically generate a photorealistic satellite image of any portion of the Earth. It is critical that every such image be georeferenced, with every pixel corresponding to a geographic location. This interface must be machine-operable - something I can run with external code to generate images that same code will use, not a GUI software. Are there any such things out there, especially open-source stuff I can run myself?

Comment: What is your reason for not wanting to use Google Earth?

Comment: you could very easily do this with Landsat data, downloaded from AWS.

Comment: @Erik How would Google Earth serve me exactly? I need a Java function to get this image and then to use it in that program. Is that possible with Google Earth?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Would that give me cloudless, normalized Google-Maps-like data though, or live images with weather and all? Is there a way to get the former through AWS?

Comment: Google offers WMS-Services of their data base, that's how it would serve you.

Answer (score 1):

This question is vague, so there are too many answers.
The first question is online or offline, i guess you want to capture google satellite or bing maps or else online, the easiest way programmatically is using WMTS service.
I'm guessing you already know the bounding box of your desired screen which is going to show the images, you can convert this bounding box to tile X,Y then find an address for a tile server to fetch the images from it, it's pretty easy. for example you can use google tile server http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x=1325&y=3143&z=13 , in this example you are getting the tile at X=1325 and Y=3143 and the zomm is 13. you can convert XY to longitude and latitude and vice versa. check this link for the related codes https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

summary :

```
1:find the bounding box
2:convert bottom left and top right of this bounding box to tile X and Y
3:find the related tiles ( you have to write a small code to find the related files beetween these 2 XY)
4:write a code to fetch the images from the WMTS address
```